# How to fix closing Excel from inside Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to close an Excel workbook from inside Access using VBA code. The following code opens the workbook and runs a VBA module in the workbook correctly. Closing the workbook prompts with the standard Save dialogue which I want to avoid.

I tried modifying the statement `.Workbooks.Close` to `.Workbooks.Close SaveChanges:=True` but that actually crashes the code.

```
Public Function Open_Share_Price_Excel()

' Change Cursor to Hourglass
Screen.MousePointer = 11

Dim Expath, ModName As String
Dim XLApp As Object
Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'
'Define where the Excel Spreadsheet is and the module to run
'

Expath = "C:\Users\peter\Documents\Financial Affairs\Shares\Share Price Bing.xlsm"
ModName = "Combined_Module"

With XLApp
    .Application.Visible = True
    .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .UserControl = True
    .Workbooks.Open Expath
    .Run ModName
    .Workbooks.Close
End With

XLApp.Quit
Set XLApp = Nothing

'Change Cursor back and display finished message

Screen.MousePointer = 0
MsgBox ("Price Update Finished - OK to Continue")

End Function
```

I tried modifying the statement `.Workbooks.Close` to `.Workbooks.Close SaveChanges:=True` but that actually crashes the code.

Any suggestions welcome.

Secondly, I would like to ensure that I close all the excel workbooks as I understand that the workbook Personal.xlsx may also be open. When I manually close the Excel spreadsheet it closes, but then EXcel immediately re-opens with a blank workbook.

Help this newbie please

Comment: Thank you, I changed that but it doesn't solve my problems. God programming tip though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What you need to do is to set the opened workbook to a variable `Set OpenedWb = .Workbooks.Open(Expath)` so you can access exactly that workbook to close it `OpenedWb.Close SaveChanges:=True`.

   `.Workbooks.Close` does not work because `Workbooks` repersents *all* workbooks and not a specific one (but you must close each workbook on its own).
2. Please note that `Dim Expath, ModName As String` only declares `ModName As String` but `Expath As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable, otherwise it is `Variant` by default. So you must use: `Dim Expath As String, ModName As String` to make them both strings.
3. Your `Function` does not return anything. Therfore it should be a procedure `Sub` instead of a function.

You would end up using something like below:

```
Public Sub Open_Share_Price_Excel()    
    ' Change Cursor to Hourglass
    Screen.MousePointer = 11
    
    '
    'Define where the Excel Spreadsheet is and the module to run
    '
    Dim Expath As String 
    Expath = "C:\Users\peter\Documents\Financial Affairs\Shares\Share Price Bing.xlsm"
    Dim ModName As String
    ModName = "Combined_Module"

    Dim XLApp As Object
    Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With XLApp
        .Application.Visible = True
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .UserControl = True
    
        Dim OpenedWb As Object
        Set OpenedWb = .Workbooks.Open(Expath)
    
        .Run ModName
    
        OpenedWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With

    XLApp.Quit
    Set XLApp = Nothing
    
    'Change Cursor back and display finished message
    Screen.MousePointer = 0

    MsgBox ("Price Update Finished - OK to Continue")
End Sub
```

Comment: The Dim OpenedWb as Workbook produce a compile error of User Defined Type not defined

Comment: Ah because you used late-binding. Sorry missed that. In case of late-binding you must use `Dim OpenedWb As Object`

Comment: Thank you!!!! Works like a charm now! That fixed the problem perfectly.

Comment: BTW - I couldn't get this to run from a Control (Button) on a form as a Sub. The RunCode event seemed to only work as a function, not sub. I tried to use the event RunMacro but it wouldn't find the macro from the drop down list on the far right of the field where you enter the Macro name.